# Format a number input (replace comma with dot)

Tags: jquery, html, forms, format

**My code**:

```
<input type="number" tabindex="3" placeholder="Item Price" step="0.01" min="0.10" max="999.99">
```

Example value inside of my `input` is `1,95`.

I want to replace `comma` with `dot`. How do I do this? I can use jQuery.

Second thing: is it possible to add `$` before numbers inside of this input? But when the form will be sent, I want to send only the number value (`1.95`) without dollar sign.

Comment: use [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 0):

Do this....

A better way in my opionion would be:

Put a $ next to the input (before it, actually).

give it position: relative; left: 20px.

The $ sign then moves into the input field.

Then, give the input field padding-left: 24px.

Voilá! The $ sign is in the input field, does not obscure anything, and cannot be removed.

And you don't need to remove it when form has to be submit

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [jQuery price formatter library](http://jquerypriceformat.com/). It seems to do what you need. From their examples:

```
$('input[type="number"]').priceFormat({
    centsSeparator: '.'
});
```

Comment: it's very nice, but when I will send the data with `POST` it will contain `prefix` from `priceformatter`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `input[type="text"]` and restrict the allowed keys to numbers and dot.

```js
$('input').keypress(function(event) {
  if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
..
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text">
```